# Check if JavaScript object contains value from other object

Tags: javascript, object

I have a project where I am working on conditional rules for a form. At this point I have two object where one are the conditions and the other are the filled in form fields which I need to check against the conditions.

I've got as far as making both of the objects, next logical step for me would be an `if statement` which checks whether or not the form object contains all of the condition object's values. (correct me if I am wrong)

I'll show both of my objects here:

```
let conditions = {
    carrier: "PostNL",
    country: "Deutschland"
}
```

```
let ticket_data = {
    carrier: "PostNL",
    client: "testdata",
    comment: "testdata",
    country: "Deutschland",
    postal_code: "testdata",
    service_level: "testdata",
}
```

As you can see, the object `ticket_data` contains all of the data the object `conditions` contains. In this case the `if statement` should return `true`. However, if one of the values wouldn't exist or wouldn't be equal to the `conditions` object it should return false.

What would be the best and easiest way to execute this?

Comment: Iterate the properties in your conditions object, check if that property exists inside your ticket, if not return false, else check if the value meets the criteria, if not return false, else continue loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the keys and check [**every**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) keys value.

```js
let conditions = { carrier: "PostNL", country: "DeutschlandTEST" }
let ticket_data = {carrier: "PostNL",client: "testdata",comment: "testdata",country: "Deutschland",postal_code: "testdata",service_level: "testdata",}
  
let checkTrue = Object.keys(conditions).every( e => ticket_data[e] )
let matchValues = Object.keys(conditions).every( e =>conditions[e] === ticket_data[e] )


if(Object.keys(conditions).every( e => ticket_data[e] )){
 console.log(`Yeah it's working`) 
}

console.log(checkTrue, matchValues)
```

Comment: This unfortunately always results in true. I edited the value `Deutschland` to `DeutschlandTEST` in one of the two objects and it still gave me true.

Comment: @mike you want to match values too ? `conditions[e] === ticket_data[e]` will be enough

Comment: Thanks, that's how I thought of it yes. Now, is it possible to make this into an if statement? So I have a block of code to execute when it returns false and when it returns true?

Comment: Could you edit your answer accordingly? Will be accepting it as the right answer,

Answer (score 2):

Object keys/entries and every. Every loops over, check for a match. If match fails it stops looping.

```js
let conditions = {
    carrier: "PostNL",
    country: "Deutschland"
}
let ticket_data = {
    carrier: "PostNL",
    client: "testdata",
    comment: "testdata",
    country: "Deutschland",
    postal_code: "testdata",
    service_level: "testdata",
}

const isMatch = Object.keys(conditions)
  .every(key => 
    conditions[key] === ticket_data[key])
    
console.log(isMatch)

const isMatch2 = Object.entries(conditions)
  .every(([key, value]) => 
    value === ticket_data[key])
    
console.log(isMatch2)
```

Comment: What happens if the given key doesn't exist in `ticket_data` ? Would that evaluate to `false` or throw an error?

Answer (score 1):

Compare the `Object.keys` of both :

```js
let conditions = {
    carrier: "PostNL",
    country: "Deutschland"
}

let ticket_data = {
    carrier: "PostNL",
    client: "testdata",
    comment: "testdata",
    country: "Deutschland",
    postal_code: "testdata",
    service_level: "testdata",
}

const ticket_data_keys = Object.keys(ticket_data);

const result = Object.keys(conditions).every(key => ticket_data_keys.includes(key));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This unfortunately always results in true. I edited the value `Deutschland` to `DeutschlandTEST` in one of the two objects and it still gave me true

Answer (score 0):

I'll do something like this:

```
let conditions = {
    carrier: "PostNL",
    country: "Deutschland"
}

let ticket_data = {
    carrier: "PostNL",
    client: "testdata",
    comment: "testdata",
    country: "Deutschland",
    postal_code: "testdata",
    service_level: "testdata",
}

const requiredProps = [
    'carrier', 'client', 'comment', 'country', 'postal_code', 'service_level'
];

const checkIfIsValid = (ticketData) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(ticketData);

    // Check for equality
    const areEquals = (keys.length == requiredProps.length) && keys.every(function(element, index) {
        return element === requiredProps[index]; 
    });

    if (!areEquals) {
        return false;
    }

    if (ticketData.carrier !== conditions.carrier) {
        return false;
    }

    if (ticketData.country !== conditions.country) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

if (checkIfIsValid(ticket_data)) {
    console.log('OK');
} else {
    console.log('ERROR');
}
```

Comment: So far (quick testing) this answer is the only one that works as expected. But I would prefer it to be dynamic in stead of making a separate if statement for every comparison. Do you see an option to make this possible?

Comment: Yes @mike sure, you can do a foreach and compare those values with the one in ticketdata